# Google cloud platform Cloud Endpoint SSL/TLS mutual handshake ESP

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, mutual-authentication, mtls

I am working on deploying an API solution on GCP where mutual SSL/TLS is required (server and client side certificates). So for the ingress of the traffic (entry point) I found that kubernetes ingress controller has this possibility (NGINX based). I am interested by cloud endpoints which has ESP (extensible service proxy which is also nginx deployment under kubernetes).

I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation whether mutual SSL/TLS is available for ESP (cloud endpoint), does anyone know the answer for this ?

Comment: I found this [documentaion](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enabling-ssl) which explain how to enable SSL/TLS for Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: @chainicko SSL is different from mTLS.

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible using Istio. Have you come across following article? which seems to suggest how to achieve MTLS for Endpoints.

https://istio.io/docs/examples/platform/endpoints/

Answer (score 0):

ESP supports mTLS.  You can specify the certificates files here

```
      proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/backend.crt;
      proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/backend.key;
```

Here is its nginx [config](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/master/start_esp/nginx-auto.conf.template#L240)