# Mutual TLS authentication on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, mutual-authentication

Is there any way to send and primarily receive Mutual TLS authenticated requests with custom certificate in Google Cloud Platform?

I would need to receive and authorize requests from a simple custom IoT device with a Mutual TLS client certificate on the device. As it is a simple use case, I do not mind using any kind of cloud environment or language, I just need it to be on the GCP with access to my Firestore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can imagine GCP Compute engine machine with installed server, which support mutual TLS (Nginx, Apache). Eventually, you can implement mutual TLS in your app, which will be running on that machine. You can implement/use mutual TLS if you have access to TCP stack (that is not probably case for Functions and App engine, where is probably TLS offloading).

Answer (score 0):

[This aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59204585/766118) states that Google Cloud Endpoints (or actually ESP) supports mTLS, which is understandable because it's nginx-based. Also [ESPv2 seems to support mTLS](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2#features). I'm looking myself into using one of these options.